# How to store boolean property for Parcelable interface?

Tags: kotlin, boolean, parcelable

I have a `data` object, `User`. One of the properties of `User` is a `Boolean`. I can't figure out how to store this `Boolean` as there is no such `writeBoolean()` provided out of the box.

From what I've searched online, one way of storing the `Boolean` property is to use the `writeInt()` method and a ternary operator.

So I tried it here:

```
data class User(val contactNumber: String,
                val email: String,
                val fullName: String,
                val isAdmin: Boolean,
                val organization: String,
                val unitNumber: String) : Parcelable {

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.writeString(contactNumber)
        dest?.writeString(email)
        dest?.writeString(fullName)
        dest?.writeInt(isAdmin ? 1 : 0)
        dest?.writeString(organization)
        dest?.writeString(unitNumber)
    }

}
```

But this syntax seems to only work with Java and not in Kotlin. I'm getting a compiler error indicating `Unexpected tokens (use ':' to separate expressions on the same line`. How do I accomplish this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator is not supported in kotlin
Use if-else instead

`writeInt(if(isAdmin) 1 else 0)`

Im using `writeValue` instead, it also usefull for nullable variables

```
dest.writeValue(this.booleanVar)
booleanVar = parcel.readValue(Boolean::class.java.classLoader) as? Boolean?
```

if it could be nullable and if not add `?: false`

**upd**: as pointed in other answers `dest` variable cannot be null. afaik it marked as nullable after code converting using Android Studio. If you use that feature better to double check your code because of convertation could work not properly sometimes.

About `?.` in general. You can rewrite it with `let` operator

```
dest?.let { it ->
  it.write(....)
```

or even better

```
dest ?: retrun
```

Comment: And renaming a variable across multiple lines to `it` is more readable, maintainable, etc?

Comment: If we are talking about `let` operator, it's possible to name variable to have a custom name instead of `it` for example `?.let { custom_name ->...`
But in this particular case writeToParcel can't have dest as nullable variable as already pointed in other answers, so no point to using let operator or ` ?: return`. 
This nullability comes after code convertation done in AS, afaik.

Answer (score 2):

1. The syntax for Java's `isAdmin ? 1 : 0` in Kotlin is `if (isAdmin) 1 else 0`.
2. `dest` can't reasonably be `null`, so you can change its type to `Parcel` and all the `?.` to `.`.

But the real answer is: use [`@Parcelize`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable) and let the compiler generate all that code, so you *can't* forget to change it when you add new properties, or get the order wrong, or...

Comment: Thanks for sharing info about @Parcelize. I didn't know about that. I'll implement that in my code now

Answer (score 1):

1.) use this handy extension function:

```
fun Parcel.readBoolean(): Boolean = readByte() > 0

fun Parcel.writeBoolean(bool: Boolean) {
    writeByte((if (bool) 1 else 0).toByte())
}
```

2.) in

> ```
> override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
> ```

`dest: Parcel!` is a **platform type**, so if you know that it will ***never*** be null, then there is zero reason to specify it as a nullable type.

Use `override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {` instead.